# How to disable the button once clicked in antd table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Getting the table values through props. The claim update function is working fine, but the record still there. once I refresh or select another tab only after that the claimed record will be removed.

```
{
  title: 'Action',
  dataIndex: 'action',
  render: (text, record) =>
          <Button class="claimBom-btn" onClick={(e) => this.handleClaim(e,text, record)} ><Icon type="plus-circle" />Claim</Button>
      }
```

This the button call for all record in the table

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just pass along the button state in the datasource.
When it is clicked mutate the datasource.

```
const [datasource, setDatasource] = useState([
{
 disabled: false,
 // others properties
}
]);


// On button click find the data and change disabled property
const onClick = (id) => {
 const source = datasource.find(source => source.id === id);
 source.disabled = true;
 setDatasource(datasource);
}
```

```
{
  title: 'Action',
  dataIndex: 'action',
  render: (text, record) =>
   <Button disabled={text.disabled} class="claimBom-btn" onClick={(e) => this.handleClaim(e,text, record)} ><Icon type="plus-circle" />Claim</Button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the `disabled` prop to the button accordingly. When calling `this.handleClaim`, set a state of which button should be disabled while handling, and pass that as a disabled prop to the button.

Comment: Yeah tried this one earlier, All buttons getting disabled in the table

Comment: @AllenBert you should keep a state object, so you flag the correct row for the button to be disabled.